# While trying to run ScheduleApex it give error

Tags: apex, asynchronous, asyncapexjob

```
//This is code
global   class Schedule1 Implements Schedulable{
  global void execute(SchedulableContext sc){
      List<Account> accounts=[SELECT ID,NAME,INDUSTRY FROM ACCOUNT WHERE NAME='BIKASH'];
      for(Account a:accounts){
          a.Phone='9121480346';
          update accounts;
      }

      }

    }
```

//THIS IS THE WAY I AM TRYING TO EXECUTE BUT IT GIVE  BELOW ERROR

> Line: 3, Column: 21
>   Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void Schedulable(String, Id, Schedule1) from the type System

```
Schedule1 sc=new Schedule1();
Id CronExp='0 38 23 26 2 2 ';
String jobId=System.Schedulable('SCJOB',CronExp,sc);
```

Answer (score 0):

The method name is **`schedule`**.

> public static String schedule(String jobName, String cronExpression, Object schedulableClass)

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, the call is incorrect. First, the method is `System.schedule`, not `System.schedulable`, and secondly, the `cronExp` should be a `String`, not an `Id`. Whenever you get a "method does not exist or incorrect signature" error, you should check the documentation or the source code (for custom code), and verify that the spelling and parameters are all correct.